# Add identifier to duplicate classes in separate nested groups

Tags: javascript, jquery

In working with a code chunk such as the following, I am attempting to add a unique class name to each instance of the class "duplicated-class" which is on the same element as the class "affiliate-logo".

Important notes:

1. "duplicated-class" represents a dynamic variable, that could be anything.
2. The desired outcome is to append the duplicated classes with a numeral ('.class-1', '.class-2', '.class-3', etc....

Here is an example the code structure:

```
<div id="integrations">
<div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
        <div class="hs-rss-item">
            <div class="rss-item-banner">
                <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
                <div class="affiliate-logo duplicate-class"><img src="" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
        <div class="hs-rss-item">
            <div class="rss-item-banner">
                <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
                <div class="affiliate-logo duplicate-class"><img src="" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
        <div class="hs-rss-item">
            <div class="rss-item-banner">
                <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
                <div class="affiliate-logo different-class"><img src="" alt=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The `post-item` group is being generated from a COS-listing with the 'duplicate-class' being pulled from the {{name}} value that must allow for duplicate value entries.

While I can find methods for producing class lists for direct descendants of the wrapping ID, I cannot seem to find (or figure out) anything that produces the result of finding the "duplicate-class" while nested more deeply in the produced structure.

My initial thoughts are to:

1. Identify the `post-item` groups
2. Find the '.affiliate-logo' class within each `post-item` group
3. Identify the second class next to '.affiliate-logo' (in this example: `.duplicate-class`) and assign it to a variable (`var = adjacentClass`) <-- this is where I get lost on how to accomplish this check.
4. Check to see if (adjacentClass) matches any other (adjacentClass) from other `post-item` groups.
5. Use counter to act as unique identifier addition (`var i = i`)
6. `if(adjacentClass === adjacentClass){ $(".duplicate-class').replaceClass('adjacentClass' + i) } else {}`

(I would actually try write that logic out in javascript, if I could figure out step 3.)

Any assistance that can be offered for this issue would be much appreciated.

---

Articles I have referenced in attempting to find a solution:

[How find nested div with same class name in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308563/how-find-nested-div-with-same-class-name-in-jquery)

[How do I access the list of classnames using javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821256/how-do-i-access-the-list-of-classnames-using-javascript-jquery)

[jquery select class inside parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394470/jquery-select-class-inside-parent-div)

[Target the 2nd instance of a CSS Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193224/target-the-2nd-instance-of-a-css-class)

** Edited to fix a terminology conflict

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify a bit:

I'd like to be able to find the 'duplicate-class' items and then add a unique value onto that class (i.e. the first 'duplicate-class' becomes 'duplicate-class-1', the second becomes 'duplicate-class-2').

Comment: Have you looked at jquery's siblings() ? That can be done with a selector, so you could simply get any sibling of the given node with the chosen class.

Comment: I've thought about siblings(), but I can't figure out how to find the elements that would have the same class from a separate nested group.

i.e. find all of the '.affiliate-group.name-a' combos on the page and then modify only the '.name-a' classes to be unique classes ('.name-a-1, .name-a-2, etc...')

Comment: I don't. The second class (subclass?) is the one that has the potential to be duplicated, but with different values. 

It could be that I have 3 '.bob' classes,  2 '.steve' classes, 14 '.tim' classes, and 1 '.tom' classes. But those are being dynamically generated by a {{name}} value from a blog post.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

In Snippet 2 we have used `.each()` twice. Once to iterate every `div.affiliate-logo` and once for the second class each `div.affiliate-logo` has. A `for` loop filters out duplicates that are stored in an array. The hardest part was what OP had trouble was with getting the second class. This is how:

> ```
> $(this).prop('classList');
> ```

In plain JavaScript, `classList` is a property when it's used without any `.add`, `.remove`, etc. it will return an array of classNames (in the comments of Snippet 2, any reference to a string in this array will be "classString").

**Review Snippet 2 in Full page mode. Details are commented in Snippet 2.**

**UPDATE 1**

> the first 'duplicate-class' becomes 'duplicate-class-1', the second becomes 'duplicate-class-2'

Not sure what you are trying to do. I think you are thinking that classes are like DOM objects as elements are. Review the Snippet and let me know if this is what you wanted or not.

**SNIPPET 1**

```js
$('.duplicate-class').each(function(idx, obj) {
  var unique = 'duplicate-class' + (idx + 1);
  $(this).addClass(unique)
  $(this).text('this is ' + unique); //This is just to show it works
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.affiliate-logo {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="integrations">
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo duplicate-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo duplicate-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo different-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```js
// .each() .affiliate-logo do this...
$('.affiliate-logo').each(function(idx, obj) {

  /* Get the classList .prop()erty and store it
  || in a var called list. list is now an array
  || of classes that belong to this particular
  || .affiliate-logo.
  */
  var list = $(this).prop('classList');

  // Store the second classString in a var called second
  var second = list[1];

  /* Create an array with the classString of 'affiliate-  
  || logo' because we already know that it will be a
  || duplicate. Call this array dupes.
  */
  var dupes = ['affiliate-logo'];

  /* for every classString that's in dupes array
  || compare it to the value of second. If there's
  || a match bust out of this loop and go on to the
  || next .affiliate-logo.
  */
  for (let a = 0; a < dupes.length; a++) {
    if (second === dupes[a]) {
      return;
    }
  }

  /* Since there were no matches, we continue.
  || Push second in the dupes array so if ever found 
  || again, second will be rejected by the previous
  || for loop.
  */
  dupes.push(second);

  /* Concat second with a dot so it'll pass as a class
  || selector then store it in a var called klass.
  */
  var klass = '.' + second;

  // each() klass will...
  $(klass).each(function(index, item) {

    /* concat second + (current)index as a string 
    || then addClass() that string to the current 
    || div.affiliate-logo.{{klass}}
    */
    $(item).addClass(second + index);

    /* insert text that shows it's new class. The
    || new unique class can be verified by F12.
    */
    $(item).text('This is ' + second + index);
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.affiliate-logo {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="integrations">
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo duplicate-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo duplicate-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo different-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo o-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo x-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo klass-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo a-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo dupe-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo bass-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo wrong-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo no-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo no-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo x-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo logo-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo long-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo x-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo duplicate-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo x-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo no-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-item" data-name="name">
    <div class="rss-card" style="">
      <div class="hs-rss-item">
        <div class="rss-item-banner">
          <img class="hs-rss-featured-image" src="" alt="">
          <div class="affiliate-logo no-class">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```